# Save generated XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to do pretty basic XML save I did it before but somehow I am having trouble with 
an error.

### Error:

**`System.NotSupportedException`**.

### Code :

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(txtXmlControl.Text);
xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/controls" + DateTime.Now+".txt"));//error

xdoc.LoadXml(txtXmlProcess.Text);
xdoc.Save("~/App_Code/processes" + DateTime.Now + ".xml");//error
```

Basically both save trials are giving me same error.

Comment: please provide more details. Its not wise to save things in App_code.

Comment: I know im just trying. + explain more details.

Comment: Check permissions of the folder you are saving to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just figured out that datetime.now makes the save name inappropriate for save. I changed it and solved the problem.. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

```
xdoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/processes" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".xml"));
```